# How to hide top bar of tabBarController programatically in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to hide the translucent top bar of my tabBar. 
[This is what happens when I run my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WaT4.png)

I can do it in storyboard by selecting 'none' under the 'Top Bar' section:
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF6qJ.png)

However, I am unsure of how to do it programatically. I have been playing around with the tabBar in my TabBarViewController, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried `navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true`?

Comment: Yes. It did not work.